# How can I fix my repo after pulling an unrelated repo?

Tags: git

I made a catastrophic error when trying to get ssh working in GIT.

I actually copied the wrong url from the server into  the config file for that repository. So, the url which I put in the config file was that of a different, but similarly named repo.

Now, I'm unable to fix the problem.

At the end of the bash prompt, it has: `GIT_DIR!|MERGING`

I have unstaged and deleted everything.

And if I try to do a hard reset to a commit hash, I get the error message `fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree`

Any idea if it is possible to clean this up at all?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to also include the commands you ran leading up to this error.

Comment: Abort the merge

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The only command I ran was `git pull` after putting the wrong url in the config. It brought down and staged all the files from the wrong repo.

Comment: @JoePhillips I tried your suggestion and ran `git merge --abort` and got the same fatal message in the post.

Comment: Why don't you just clone into a new folder, using the correct URL?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah. I think I will do that. There's only about 4 commits behind origin and I can manually sort that out. My own fault for a careless mistake. Thanks.

Comment: how exactly did you "deleted everything"?

Comment: @max630 In Sourcetree, I right-clicked on everything in the Unstaged Files pane and clicked Remove from the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

From the info in your question : your repo is currently halfway into a merge, which did not complete because of a conflict (reminder : `git pull` is a shortcut to `git fetch && git merge`, so this is a perfectly reasonable state, it just means "merging in the remote changes" require some manual attention).

You can turn back to the commit you were in before that merge by running :

```
git merge --abort
```

After that, you can fix the url of your remote :

```
# I guess your remote is 'origin', use the correct remote name otherwise
git remote set-url origin ssh://correct url
```

update your view of the remote :

```
git fetch
```

From there, you should be in a pretty clean state, and be able to see what changes need to be reverted and what changes should be pushed.